# Navigation Drawer shows error to the Java File when maps integrated

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to have a Navigation Drawer, on of the activity will be the current location. But when i set my code in the drawer if statement i get an error and doesnt give any solution.

this is my MainActivity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


    if (id == R.id.nav_home_layout)
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newFrameLayout, new MapsActivityTest()).commit();
    else if (id == R.id.nav_earning_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newFrameLayout, new EarningActivity()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_campaign_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newFrameLayout, new CampaignActivity()).commit();
    }  else if (id == R.id.nav_vehicle) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newFrameLayout, new Vehicle()).commit();
    }  else if (id == R.id.nav_alerts) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newFrameLayout, new Alerts()).commit();
    }  else if (id == R.id.nav_faqs) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newFrameLayout, new FAQS()).commit();
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_track_location) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

MapsActivityTest() class shows an error on the if statement.

This is the MapsActivityTest()

```
 public class MapsActivityTest extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_test);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use a switch case instead of so many if-else-if statements?

Comment: check if you have imported correct version of `FragmentManahge`. it should be of v4.

Comment: what kind of error do you have?

Comment: I thin if you want to use Navigation Drawer use it with `fragments` with it. You need to extends all Classes with Fragments instead of Fragmentactivity.

Comment: @Aradhna its not the test clause thats causing this issue but the statement that calls the MapsActivityTest class

Comment: @Konstantin no idea {fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newFrameLayout, new MapsActivityTest()).commit();} is an error and build doesnt complete

Comment: Yes, as @userAndroid say, FragmentActivity is not the same that Fragment. Change it to solve you problem.

Comment: @Konstantin no difference mate.

Comment: @userAndroid no difference mate.

Comment: past here text of you error. is important

Comment: @Konstantin `Error:(94, 77) error: incompatible types: MapsActivityTest cannot be converted to Fragment`

Comment: Show full code of you MapsActivityTest. code that shown here is wrong, because to use Fragment you need implements onCreateView methed where create View. See google docs

Comment: @Konstantin The code is too long where would you want me to send it to you? do you have an email or something?

Comment: According you error text, the problem throws because you MapsActivityTest is not Fragment. See google doc how to create Fragment and change you MapActivityTest according docs.

Comment: @Konstantin found it had to change the MapsActivityTest to extend to Fragments